# CSS: A transition element does not affect other

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm wanting to do this transition effect, but it only works on the first div, on Monday that aims to affect the first, nothing happens.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #firstElement:hover + #secondElement {
    color:red;
    }
    #secondElement:hover + #firstElement {
    color:blue;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="firstElement">Hover</p>
    <p id="secondElement">Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why this doesn't work should be clear from the other answers. Here's a solution.

```
<div id="elements">
    <p id="firstElement">Hover</p>
    <p id="secondElement">Hello</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#elements:hover #secondElement:not(:hover) {
  color:red;
}
#elements:hover #firstElement:not(:hover) {
  color:blue;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CQBM8/)

Comment: glad that you have a CSS way with some change in HTML, learned something. +1

Comment: Thank you! that was it! 
I will use this because I can not use JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

first you need to set `transition` (if you mean transition and not hover) to the elements like this:

```
#firstElement:hover + #secondElement {
    color:red;
    transition:color 0.5s ease;  /* this is an example  */
}

#secondElement:hover + #firstElement {   /*  this is not right selector  */
    color:blue;
    transition:color 0.5s ease;  /* this is an example  */
}
```

and second there is no backward in CSS, you can just change color of second element by hovering first element.

for doing that you can to use jQuery.

use this JQuery code:

```
$("#secondElement").hover(function(){
    $("#firstElement").toggleClass("firstcolor");
});
```

and add this CSS:

```
.firstcolor{
    color:blue;
}
```

[**here is DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/XFaSd/)

***note:** this is not only way*

Comment: You really don't need to use javascript for this. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240983/css-a-transition-element-does-not-affect-other/20241286#20241286)

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels I didn't say "NEED", I said you "CAN" use JQuery. your solution need some change in HTML

Answer (score 0):

the psuedo hover effect only works on parent-child relationships.

so if you have a menu where Toys is the parent, and barbie dolls, car trucks, and legos are the 3 child elements, you can do psuedo classes.

For example if you did

```
#toys:hover #barbiedolls { background: red; }
```

that would work. But if you tried doing

```
#barbiedolls:hover #toys { background: red; }
```

that would not work. Neither would

```
#barbiedolls:hover #cartrucks { background: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Adjacent sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

> Adjacent sibling selectors have the following syntax: E1 + E2, where E2 is the subject of the selector. The selector matches if E1 and E2 share the same parent in the document tree and **E1 immediately precedes E2**, ignoring non-element nodes (such as text nodes and comments).

This means `#firstElement` precedes `#secondElement`, therefore it works.

But `#secondElement` doesn't precede `#firstElement`, therefore it doesn't work.